# Neccesary and sufficient condition for geodesic curves and they velocity vector to be parallel

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, geodesic

I'm trying to resolve the following:

"Let $M$ be a regular and oriented surface, and $\alpha = \alpha(t)$ a regular parametrized curve in $M$. An let $\mathbf{V}=\alpha'(t)$. We know that if $\mathbf{V}$ is a parrallel vector field (this meaning its covariant derivative is zero) then $\alpha$ is a geodesic curve.
Prove that the reciprocal isn't true, and give a necessary and sufficient condition for it to be true."

I think I have proven that if the curve is parametrized by its natural parameter (arc length).
$$ \alpha (\text{geodesic}) \Rightarrow K_g =(\vec{N},\dot{\alpha},\ddot{\alpha}) = 0$$
$$\left. \begin{array}{l}
\dot{\alpha} \perp \vec{N}\\
\dot{\alpha} \perp \ddot{\alpha}
\end{array}\right\} \Rightarrow \ddot{\alpha}\parallel \vec{N}$$
Which is what we wanted, but I still can't disprove what I was asked to (I can't find a counter example) And clearly it isn't a necessary condition, since the equator of a sphere with radius $R$ and center at the origin parametrized as $R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0)$ (which isn't naturally parametrized) has a parallel velocity vector.

Comment: This is a misleading question. Some texts/people refer to a parametrized curve as a *pre-geodesic* if its trace is a geodesic but it fails to be a constant-speed parametrized curve. I would like to see the precise definition of *a geodesic curve* in your text.

Comment: A curve $\alpha$ is geodesic if its geodesic curvature $K_g(t) = \frac{1}{|\alpha'(t)|^3}(\vec{N},\alpha',\alpha'') \equiv 0$

Comment: OK, so all you need for your task is a parametrization with non-constant speed of a geodesic curve. I now see that you’d posted the answer yourself, earlier.

Answer (score 1):

$|\alpha'|'=0$ is a N&S condition:
$$
\alpha' = R\vec{t} \Rightarrow \ \alpha'' = R\vec{t'} \\
$$
Here $\vec{t}$ is the tangent vector, and since it is unitary, we get
$$
\vec{t} \perp \vec{t'} \Rightarrow \ \alpha' \perp \alpha''
$$
Then since $K_g = 0 = \frac{1}{R^3}(\vec{N},\alpha',\alpha'')$ and given the perpendicular relation before, the only way this determinat can be zero is if $\alpha'' \parallel \vec{N}$ Which is the same as having a covariant derivate zero.

In the other direction it is easy to see that if geodesic implies covariant derivative equal to $0$:
$$
\alpha'' = (|\alpha'|\vec{t})’=|\alpha'|'\vec{t} + |\alpha'|\vec{t'}
$$
And for this to be paralle to the perpendicular we need $|\alpha'|'$ to be zero.
A counter example to proof can be the $\theta = \theta_0$ of the revolution surface $(f(x)\sin\theta, f(x)\cos\theta, z(x)$